# How do I take the punctuation off each line of a column of an xlsx file in Python?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlsx

I have an excel file (.xlsx) with a column having rows of strings. I used the following code to get the file:

```
import pandas as pd   

df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")  
db = df['Column Title']
```

I am removing the punctuation for the first line (row) of the column using this code:

```
import string

translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
sent_pun = db[0].translate(translator)
```

I would like to remove the punctuation for each line (until the last row). How would I correctly write this with a loop? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well given that this code is working for one value and producing the right kind of results then you can write it in a loop as

```
for row in rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=6, max_col=3):
    for cell in row:
        translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
        sent_pun = db[0].translate(translator)
```

Change the arguments (number of rows and columns) as per your need.